# C++ Syntax Error: Program Exited With Non-Zero Status

Tags: c++, syntax

I'm using repl.it to write my C++. So far I have learned about conditionals, loops, and functions. Right now I am trying to write a program that inputs two integers and finds the Least Common Multiple and the Greatest Common Denominator. So far I have written most of my code, however there is a problem.

**"exited with non-zero status"**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
int number1 = 0;
int number2 = 0;
int calc = 0;
int lcm = 0;
cout << "Give me two integers, and I will calculate the Least Common Multiple and the Greatest Common Divisor." << endl;

while (number1 <= 0) {

    cout << "Enter your first number. Cant be negative" << endl;
    cin >> number1; }

while (number2 <= 0) {
    cout << "Enter your second number. Cant be negative" << endl;
    cin >> number2; }

while(number2 != 0) { ///Greatest Common Divisor
    calc = number1 % number2;
    lcm = (number1*number2) / calc;
    number1 = number2;
    number2 = calc;
}



cout << "Least Common Multiple is " << lcm << endl;

cout << "Greatest Common divisor is " << number1 << endl;
}
```

So I'm not sure if it's a syntax error or it's because of repl.it, but I'm really struggling to figure this out.

Thanks

Comment: Add `return 0;` to the end of your main() function.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: There's no need. `main` returns 0 by default. In both C++ and C.

Comment: @jrod: You should always post the inputs you used and the exact error message.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Wow, thanks for all the help! I really appreciate it! (:

Answer (score 1):

While loop checks number2 value in end of the loop, but when you calculate calc, sometime this value is zero, then in next step program exited with divide by zero exception. you can prevent this problem by adding this line to your code after calculating calc variable:

```
if (calc == 0 ) break;
```

In additional your code does not work correctly, for example set number1 = 30 and number2 = 18!

I use binary method for calculating GCD and then calculate LCM by using GCD.

```
            #include <iostream>
            #include <math.h>   //  for pow(2,d)
            using namespace std;


            int main() 
            {
                int gcd, lcm, a, b, g, number1 = 0, number2 = 0, d=0;
                cout << "Give me two integers, and I will calculate the Greatest Common Divisor and the Least Common Multiple." << endl;

                while (number1 <= 0) {
                    cout << "Enter your first number. Cant be negative" << endl;
                    cin >> number1; 
                }
                // using binary method to calculating GCD:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor
                while (number2 <= 0) {
                    cout << "Enter your second number. Cant be negative" << endl;
                    cin >> number2; 
                }    
                a = number1;
                b = number2;
                while (((a%2)==0) && ((b%2)==0)) {
                    a = a/2;
                    b = b/2;
                    d = d+1;
                }
                while (a != b) {
                    if ((a%2) == 0) {
                        a = a/2;
                    } else if ((b%2)==0) {
                        b = b/2;
                    } else if (a>b) {
                        a = (a-b) /2;
                    } else {
                        b = (b-a)/2;
                    }
                }
                g = a;
                cout << "\ng: " << g << "\td: " << d << "\tpower(2,d): " << pow(2,d);
                gcd = g * pow(2,d); // power(2,d) with math.h library
                lcm = (number1*number2)/gcd;   // according to LCM(a,b) = (a*b)/GCD(a,b)
                cout << "\nGreatest Common Divisor is " << gcd << " and Least Common Multiple is " << lcm << endl;
            }
```

Comment: The diagnosis is OK, the fix is not.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf

Comment: I'm not sure of the "binary gcd" you present, but it seems like it, at best, reduces numbers by halving them in each iteration. The ordinary Euclid's algorithm, implemented with remainder operation, is both much simpler and faster than that. Knuth discussed its performance in vol I of the TAOCPP, I don't recall, sorry. But, it's seriously much simpler. Here's a link to a little essay I wrote about Euclid's: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2oiI2reHOh4Q0RfR1R1enEza2s/view).

Comment: Thanks for the essay.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check which number is bigger, because if you set `number1=18` and `number2=30` then `number1%number2` will be 18, and then you see where it goes - to the wrong output. Also, the fix suggested by Hossein Nazari is good to avoid the exception, but you GCD is stored in `number2` if you follow that fix. For example 30 and 18:

```
30%18 = 12
calc = 12
if(calc==0) break;
(lcm routine)
number1 = 18
number2 = 12

18%12 = 6
calc=6
if(calc==0) break;
(lcm routine)
number1 = 12
number2 = 6

12%6=0
calc=0
if(calc==0) break;
<done>
```

I would rather remove the lcm computation from your loop entirely, in this case, you'd get your GCD in `number1` as planned, then just calculate LCM by formula `(number1*number2)/GCD` which would be `30*18/6 = 90;`

Answer (score -1):

Hi just change data type of this two

```
float calc = 0;
float lcm = 0;
```

Hi @Cheers and hth, I have executed code here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php, and got this exception - Floating point exception,
After i have changed data type from int to float i got this values
Enter your first number. Cant be negative
10
Enter your second number. Cant be negative
20
Least Common Multiple is inf
Greatest Common divisor is 10

Comment: **−1** It doesn't make sense to change the type.

Comment: #Cheers and hth. - Alf  please review the answer now and check on online execution.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Is it make sense? please check output and let me know.

Comment: When the floating point implementation supports infinities and NaN then the floating point division by 0 doesn't crash the program as the integer division by 0 did. But that's not the problem: the problem is that division by 0 happens, at all.

Comment: Sorry m not getting you Cheers and hth, Its simple that with this code there was no errors as Jrod has that is solved.

Comment: Consider, an even simpler way to avoid (what you regard as) the error is to remove all the code in `main`. That's ***also*** a change that transforms the hard crash into an erroneous result. And it's a simpler change.